# Is $z=0$ a removable singularity of $f(z)=z^{1/2}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

I met some problem when I dealt with the complex function $z^{\alpha}$($\alpha$ is not an integer). For example, $\alpha=1/2$. If $z\neq0$, $f(z)=z^{1/2}=\exp(1/2\log{z})$ which is holomorphic in $C\setminus{\{0\}}$. Also, if $|z|\leq1$ and $z\neq0$, we have $|f(z)|=|z|^{1/2}\leq1$. That is, $f$ is bounded on $\{z:|z|\leq1\}\setminus{\{0\}}$. By Riemann's theorem removable theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann's_theorem), $z=0$ is a removable singularity. But it seems that it couldn't happen. Here is a contradiction. If above is true, the value $f(0)$ should be 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
f(0)
&=\frac{1}{2\pi{i}}\int_{|\zeta|=1}\frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta-0}d\zeta\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi{i}}\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{\frac{i\theta}{2}}d\theta\\
&=2/\pi.
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
Also, $f(0)$ should be 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
f(0)
&=\frac{1}{2\pi{i}}\int_{|\zeta|=1/2}\frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta-0}d\zeta\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi{i}}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}e^{\frac{i\theta}{2}}d\theta\\
&=\sqrt{2}/\pi.
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
This is a contradiction.

I don't know why this will happen. Actually, I thought $f(z)=z^{1/2}$ is not analytic at $z=0$. But I can't convince myself. Could you tell me something about the behavior of $f$ at $z=0$? Thank you very much.

Comment: $\sqrt z$ is not defined on $\mathbb C\setminus \{0\}$.

Comment: +1 for @asdq 's comment. Note that $z=0$ is not a pole or essential singularity either. It is a ramification point (branch point).

Comment: @ asdq, why you said that $z^{1/2}$ is not defined on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$? I mean, $z^{1/2}$ is well-defined by $e^{1/2\log{z}}$ on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: The logarithm isn't well-defined on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$. There are infinitely many holomorphic branches of $\log$ on small enough neighbourhoods of each $z \in \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$, but one can't assemble them to get a continuous logarithm on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$. Similarly, on every small enough connected neighbourhood of $z \neq 0$ there are two holomorphic branches of the square root, but one can't assemble them to get a continuous square root on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$.

Comment: @ Daniel Fischer. Thank you. I understood what you mean by ``not well-defined". They are multi-valued.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I figure out what I ignore. Since the logarithm is multi-valued, we can only consider it "locally" when we consider the principle branch. Thus the function $f(z)=z^{1/2}=e^{1/2\log{z}}$ (considering the principle branch) can be only holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus(-\infty,0]$ but not $\mathbb{C}\setminus{\{0\}}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a removable singularity. Moreover, it is not an *isolated singularity*.

The classification into "removable, pole, essential" is for isolated singularities only: i.e., under the assumption that the function is holomorphic in a punctured neighborhood of the point. Riemann's theorem is also for this kind of singularities only.

The point $z=0$ is a *branch point* of the function $f(z) = z^{1/2}$, which is another story. It can be classified as an *algebraic* branch point, as for each $z$ in a neighborhood of $0$, there are only finitely many values taken by the branches of $f$. One can push some of the theory of Laurent series to such  branch points by using series with fractional powers of $z$; the *Complex Analysis* book by Ahlfors does this.